# How to draw kmeans clusters with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, visualization

I have 4 clusters that I would like to visualize with ggplot.
I tried to plot it with ggplot but I didn't know how make it look like the figure below. My result was just to present scatterplot showing points not grouped by similarity with centroids.

> - **top50combos_freq** : has two columns[freq,freq1]
> - **top50combos_freq.ckmeans** : took the result of kmeans with 4 clusters    as parameters.

```
plot(top50combos_freq[top50combos_freq.ckmeans1$cluster==1,],
     col = "red",
     xlim = c(min(top50combos_freq[,1]), max(top50combos_freq[,1])),
     ylim = c(min(top50combos_freq[,2]), max(top50combos_freq[,2]))
     )
points(top50combos_freq[top50combos_freq.ckmeans1$cluster==2,],
       col="blue")
points(top50combos_freq[top50combos_freq.ckmeans1$cluster==3,],
       col="seagreen")
points(top50combos_freq.ckmeans1$centers, pch=2, col="green")
```

Any help to make this plot with ggplot will appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to create 2 data frames:

- one for actual data points, with a factor variable specifying the cluster,
- the other one only with centroids (number of rows same as the number of clusters).

Then you might want to plot the first data frame as usual, but then add additional geom, where you specify new data frame.

Example using `iris` data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Data frame with actual data points
plotDf <- iris 
# Data frame with centroids, one entry per centroid
centroidsDf <- data.frame(
  Sepal.Length = tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean),
  Sepal.Width = tapply(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species, mean)
)

# First plot data, colouring by cluster (in this case Species variable)
ggplot(
  data = plotDf,
  aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, col = Species)
) +
  geom_point() +
  # Then add centroids 
  geom_point(
    data = centroidsDf,                     # separate data.frame
    aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width),
    col = "green",                          # notice "col" and "shape" are
    shape = 2)                              # outside aes()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I need to change text on the y axis from {10;15;20;25;30} to a list of significant text. Is this possible with ggplot ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a list of significant text", but you can set ticks to whatever values you prefer by adding `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2, 3.5, 4.2))` to the code above and substituting the vector with the required values. Is that what you need?

Comment: Sorry I am replying before I try it, but it looks exactly what I want. Because I have a list for example {Bob, Jack, Robert, ...}, and I just want to make them appear on the ticks instead of 1,2,3,4,5. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you probably want something like this: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2, 3.5, 4.2), labels = c("Bob", "Jack", "Robert"))`, where `breaks` specify the position and `labels` specify actual text at those positions.